# Someone help explain the Big O complexiity of this java code, I'm so confused

Tags: big-o

```
 for( int i = n; i > 0; i-- ) {
      for( int j = 1; j < n; j *= 2 ) {
       for( int k = 0; k < j; k++ ) {
          ... // constant number C of operations
            }
        }
      }
```

for this code,  N= 2^m, and the correct answer is O(N^2). my professor said the middle and inner loops are dependent on one another, so the middle loop and inner loop together form a series 2^0 + 2^1 + 2^2+ ... + 2 (log(N)),  the sum of that series is 2N. So the two inner loops together form 2N. 2N * n ^ 2 = O(n^2). Someone please explain this part to me, how did my professor get the answer 2N? because I thought it's going to be Log N * N for the inner and middle loops.

but from my perspective, don't I just take big O for each loop, starting from outer, N * log N * n = n^2 * log N. why is my way wrong? and how do I know when to plus or multiply.

Answer (score 0):

The first loop iterates N times, the second loop iterates `log n` times as `j` doubles on each loop.

For each iteration of the second loop, the third loop iterates `j` times. then first it iterates 1 time as `j` is 1, when `j` becomes 2, it iterates 2 times, when `j` becomes 4 it iterates 4 times.....
then these two loops iterates 1 + 2 + 4 + ... 2^log n = 2 * N - 1

Then the time of whole program is N * (2*N - 1) = O(N^2)

Comment: so you are saying the final last two loops are linked together, therefore I should not look at them as log n and n but instead O(n)

Comment: yes, the last loop is dependent to the `j` which varies in the second loop, you can not multiply iterations because the number of iterations is not constant, you must sum the last loop iterations per each iteration of the second loop.